# Segmentation fault. C. GDB

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, gdb

I'm trying to write a library (array.c array.h) which will create an array of blocks in memory. The size of this array is Array.size. The size of each block is constant and it is Array.block_size. Each block should be filled witch random characters.

An array will be either static or dynamic. For static it'll be stored in a global_array of char. In a dynamic case it's an Array of pointers to blocks.

IN DYNAMIC appears an "segmentation fold error", when I try to add 70 blocks to my Array.

Why this error appears and is there an easy way to find such error using gdb?

[image]

main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "array.h"



int main(int argc, char *argv[] )
{


  initArray(50,10,0);
   int i;

   for(i=0;i<70;i++){
     addBlock();

   }

    return 0;
}
```

array.h

```
#ifndef ARRAY_H
#define ARRAY_H

struct Array {
   char *stat ;
   char **dyn ;
   int size;
   int block_size;
   int is_static;
};
struct Array Array;

void initArray(int size, int block_size, int is_static);
void addBlock();



#endif // ARRAY_H
```

array.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "array.h"


#define  GLOBAL_SIZE 100000
#define INFTY 32767
char global_array[GLOBAL_SIZE];

struct Array Array={NULL,NULL,-1,-1,-1};


void initArray(int size, int block_size, int is_static){

    Array.size = size;
    Array.block_size = block_size;
    Array.is_static = is_static;
    if(Array.is_static){ // static


    }else{ //dynamic

        Array.dyn = malloc(Array.size * sizeof(char*));
        int i;
        for(i=0;i<Array.size;i++){
            Array.dyn[i] = NULL;
        }

        Array.stat =NULL;
    }

}



char* genRandom() {
    static const char alphanum[] =     "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    char *s = malloc(Array.block_size*sizeof(char));
    for (int i = 0; i < Array.block_size; i++) {
        s[i] = alphanum[rand() % (sizeof(alphanum) - 1)];
    }

    return s;
}

void addBlock(){

    if(Array.is_static){
        //some code
    }else{ //Seach for NULL pointer in Array.dyn. Point it to new block of chars.

        int flag = 0;
        for(int i=0;i<Array.size;i++){
            if(Array.dyn[i] == NULL){
                Array.dyn[i] = malloc(Array.block_size*sizeof(char));
                char* t = genRandom();
                int j;
                for(j=0;j<Array.block_size;j++){
                    Array.dyn[i][j] = t[j];
                }
                flag =1;

                free(t);
                t =NULL;


                break;

            }

        }

        if(!flag){ // There is no NULL pointer in Array.dyn. I have to realloc Array.dyn and add a new pointer 
            printf("f\n");
            Array.size ++;

            Array.dyn = realloc(Array.dyn,Array.size*sizeof(char*));

            char *t = genRandom();
            for(int i=0;i<Array.block_size;i++){
                Array.dyn[Array.size-1][i] =  t[i];
            }
            free(t);

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: `s = "1234567890";  return s;` it might work better without that !

Comment: When you allocated the array of pointers the memory size was `Array.size  * sizeof(char*)` but when you reallocate this, you forgot the size of each element by using `realloc(Array.dyn, Array.size);`. This too should be `Array.size  * sizeof(char*)` but the program still crashes.

Comment: Array.dyn[Array.size-1] = malloc(Array.block_size*sizeof(char));

Comment: I forgot to add this line after i increased Array.size. Now code works.